# jvisualvm - How to provide an icon and another name than the invoking class for my program?

Tags: java, jvisualvm

I have an application where I want to be able to provide my own icon and descriptive text for jvisualvm.  (I do not want to configure jvisualvm, just provide better metadata from my application)

The best would be at runtime since we have distinct behaviour determined at runtime, which would be nice to have reflected in the label/icon.  Makes it easier to 1) locate ourselves, but also 2) for endusers to locate in a support situation.

I did search for this earlier, but did not locate this easily.  Is it buried in the JMX-stuff?

Suggestions?  I have full control over the application in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a new ApplicationType. Have a look here for how to do it

http://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/getting_started_extending_visualvm_part

Comment: So it can only be done by extending jvisualvm, and not in the default configuration?

Comment: Yes,, you need to write your own plugin for it. I read that netbeans has templates for writing visualvm plugins, but I haven't tried it.