# JMX icon and application title

Tags: icons, jmx, jvisualvm

I have an application that exposes several MBeans using spring-jmx. When I open JVisualVM the program is listed as com.package.Main, and it has a default icon. How do I change this. I know it is possible as my Intellij IDE has an icon, and simply says "Intellij Platform".

Comment: dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334907

Comment: Thanks, can't believe i missed that post.